# how can I call ruby function basename in puppet

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

I'd like to call function `File.basename` which is available in Ruby. Is it possible in puppet?

Something like:

```
$filename = basename($download_url)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ruby functions are not directly available in Puppet, but you can use inline_template:

```
$filename = inline_template('<%= File.basename(download_url) %>')
```

Comment: Thanks! I still find puppet syntax quite confusing... it's not ruby :)

Comment: No, you're thinking of Chef, Which Is Ruby.

Comment: @TomO'Connor Not anymore, Chef 11 uses Erlang.

Comment: Eugh.  That *is* sickening.

Answer (score 1):

meanwhile it is possible to use the [puppetlabs-stdlib](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#basename) which provides a `basename()` function.

> Returns the basename of a path (optionally stripping an extension).

```
basename('/path/to/a/file.ext') returns 'file.ext'
basename('relative/path/file.ext') returns 'file.ext'
basename('/path/to/a/file.ext', '.ext') returns 'file'
```

Comment: Yes, the function seems to be available since `puppetlabs-stdlib 4.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not call arbitrary Ruby functions in a Puppet manifest, but you can do so in Puppet templates which use ERB. Have a look at the [`inline_template` function](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#inlinetemplate), which might be useful for your use case.